# Arduino is not freeing up RAM memory

Tags: c++, memory, arduino, md5, esp8266

I'm using Arduino mega with MD5 library and ESP8266 with SoftwareSerial. The problem is that after 370 loops, Arduino auto-restart due to lack of memory. I used FreeMemory to troubleshoot, I noticed the problem is the decreasing of available memory with each loop. It is weird behavior, because it only appears when I use AT commands along with MD5, however if I separate the sketch in two sketches they work properly without memory problems. 
My original sketch is a quite more complex, but I reduced to the essential code the example showed bellow in order to be more clear, the behavior is the same, so if i fix it i will be able to fix the my original sketch

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <MemoryFree.h>
#include <MD5.h>


void setup() {
  // initialize the digital pin as an output.
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Starting");
  Serial1.begin(115200);
  delay(200);
}

// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {

    Serial1.println("AT");  
    delay(100); 
    Serial.println(Serial1.readString());
    Serial.println("-----------");

    unsigned char* hash=MD5::make_hash("hello world, this an example");
    //generate the digest (hex encoding) of our hash
    char *md5str = MD5::make_digest(hash, 16);
    //print it on our serial monitor
    Serial.println(md5str);
    //Give the Memory back to the System if you run the md5 Hash generation in a loop
    free(md5str);
    Serial.println(freeMemory());

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the `hash` variable doesn't need to be free'd as well?

Comment: Is it supposed to? Can it not keep that allocated memory hanging around in case it needs it again later?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the source code of `make_hash`:

```cpp
unsigned char* MD5::make_hash(const void *arg)
{
    MD5_CTX context;
    unsigned char * hash = (unsigned char *) malloc(BLOCK_SIZE);
    MD5Init(&context);
    MD5Update(&context, arg, strlen((char*)arg));
    MD5Final(hash, &context);
    return hash;
}
```

As you can see, there is a `malloc()` in there for the returned `hash` variable. Therefore you should invoke `free(hash)` at the end of each loop iteration.

If you need to keep `hash` around, put it in the *global scope* and create it *only once* in the `setup()` function.

Comment: Thank you! next time I will keep in mind take a look at the library source code.